# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DatabaseReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I get the error Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DatabaseReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database) how can i fix this error? I am trying to set an int in the realtime database but i get this error onclick, does anyone know what i did wrong and how to fix it.

```
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    child: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icons8-money-50.png"),),),

                  Text('$money', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple.shade900)),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 8, 0),
                child:TextButton(
                    child: Text("Buy Credits"),
                    onPressed: () async {

                     fetchOffers(context);
                     DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123");
                     await ref.set({
                       "Credits": 10,
                     });
                    },
                  ))
                ],
              ),
```

The main page where i initialized firebase:

```
Future main() async{

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  );


  runApp( MyApp());
}
```

And the initstate:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    _checkFirstTime();
  }
```

Can anyone pleas help me with this problem. I have used the Cli to link the app to Firebase.

Comment: If you have just installed the plugin, then the IDEs like VSCode does not load the plugin immediately. If that is the case, try completely closing your IDE and starting again.

Comment: Tank you very much the error is gone now. but now i get the error premisson denied. How can i fix this

Comment: Create a new question with more details like what is the error, what kind of permission is required and the related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart Android studio, then it will work.